# ternary operator processing error laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, ternary-operator

I have this problem. In plain PHP, this function is working perfectly and returns correct result:

```
$focos_3[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_3) ? array_search("$c", $cidades_3) : ('') ) ]
```

**OBS:** sometimes $c is not set.

But when I put it in Laravel its stops working and throw me "Undefined index:". Without index indication.

Doing some tests, I found that if I do this:

```
array_search("$c", $cidades_3)
```

or this

```
in_array("$c", $cidades_3)
```

works perfectly, even if $c is not set.

**Some answers:**

$cidades_3 starts at index 1
$focos_3 is array of values that will return a result on position that was requested.

The whole function which I need to get working is this:

```
foreach ($cidades as $c) 
    {
        $registros = array(
            "Estado"    => $estados[$c],
            "Municipio" => $c, 
            "tres_dias" => $focos_3[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_3) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_3) : ('') ) ], 
            "dois_dias" => $focos_2[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_2) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_2) : ('') ) ], 
            "um_dia"    => $focos_1[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_1) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_1) : ('') ) ], 
            "total"     => (
                                         ($focos_3[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_3) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_3) : ('') ) ]) + 
                                         ($focos_2[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_2) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_2) : ('') ) ]) + 
                                         ($focos_1[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_1) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_1) : ('') ) ])
                                         ) 
            );
    }
```

And yes, its similar problem to this question ([Laravel breaks entire app on PHP notices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497788/laravel-breaks-entire-app-on-php-notices)), but there we have not very goo solution (suppression error).

Comment: This seems to be an issue related to error reporting options. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497788/laravel-breaks-entire-app-on-php-notices

Comment: What is supposed to happen if $c is found at index 0 in $cidades_3? Or if the value of $c is 'x' and the array contains an entry with the value 0 (or vice versa)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel breaks entire app on PHP notices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497788/laravel-breaks-entire-app-on-php-notices)

Comment: How is `$focos_3` used? The error states that the index `''` is not defined, so that is not related to the `array_search` in your ternary operator, but to the index `''` on (most likely) the `$focos_3` array.

Comment: If array search returns 0 (which may be valid) you'll get `''` returned by the ternary operator which is probably undefined. An undefined index is a warning which PHP usually swallows or writes somewhere, but Laravel treats as an unhandled exception.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Indeed, in this case it was easier to suppress warning message with Laravel.
Putting an '@' here solved error.

```
foreach ($cidades as $c) 
{
    @$registros = array(
        "Estado"    => $estados[$c],
        "Municipio" => $c, 
        "tres_dias" => $focos_3[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_3) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_3) : ('') ) ], 
        "dois_dias" => $focos_2[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_2) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_2) : ('') ) ], 
        "um_dia"    => $focos_1[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_1) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_1) : ('') ) ], 
        "total"     => (
                                     ($focos_3[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_3) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_3) : ('') ) ]) + 
                                     ($focos_2[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_2) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_2) : ('') ) ]) + 
                                     ($focos_1[ (array_search("$c", $cidades_1) >=0 ? array_search("$c", $cidades_1) : ('') ) ])
                                     ) 
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if is set

```
if(isset($var){
//execute function
}
```