# Undefined Variable in laravel 8 Using sql

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have an issue using `@if`, `@elseif` and `@else` statement on blade.php using laravel 8, It always return as Undefined Variable. How can I resolve this problem? Or is there any other away around?

On my `index.blade.php`:

```js
@if($exi)
@include('renew.modify.exi')
@elseif($exi2)
@include('renew.modify.exi2')
@elseif($exp)
@include('renew.modify.exp')
@endif
```

On my `modifyController.php`:

```js
if (count((array) $exi) > 0) {
  return View::make('renew.modify.index', ['exi' => $exi]);
}
elseif(count((array) $exi2) > 0) {
  return View::make('renew.modify.index', ['exi2' => $exi2]);
}
elseif(count((array) $exp) > 0) {
  return View::make('renew.modify.index', ['exp' => $exp]);
} else {
  Session::flash('flash_message', 'Something went wrong on your credentials. Please double check your inputs. If you don\'t have any. You can create here: ');
  return Redirect::to('renewView');
}
```

My goal is, when the controller detect that `count((array) $something)` detect then it will return to the same index.blade then the `@if, @elseif and @else` will be triggered, but when `$exp` detected the my two variable will be `undefined`. How do i resolve this problem?

Comment: Pass the other two variables to each view, even if the value may be 0, so that all 3 are defined. Only one of the 3 should evaluate true, and all variables will be present to the blade. That is at least one way.

Comment: I was using the same method on laravel 5 and its working, but now using laravel 8 it starts to make it undefined.

Comment: Ok, but that was 3 versions ago? Apparently, some were [reporting this back with Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497788/laravel-breaks-entire-app-on-php-notices) (and 4), so there must be configuration differences? I don't know that I would try to subvert notices, but know that with PHP 8+, undefined vars are now warnings, not notices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isset() method for that.
change your @if condition like this way

```
@if(isset($exi))
@include('renew.modify.exi')
@elseif(isset($exi2))
@include('renew.modify.exi2')
@elseif(isset($exp))
@include('renew.modify.exp')
@endif
```

may it helps ...

Comment: Yep, I should read the document again, I literally forgot about the `isset`. Thank you very much!